# Substitute for function wrappers

Tags: c++, code-duplication

I have a C++ class that manages two connections (source and target). Every operation on the connection is two phased, a prepare phase and a commit phase. Some of the operations I would like to do on both connections and using almost the same parameters.

I.e.,

```
mngr::init_conn(int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    m_conn.prepare_init(source_id, var1, var2, var3);
    m_conn.commit();

    m_conn.prepare_init(target_id, var1, var2, var3);
    m_conn.commit();
}

mngr::update_conn(int var1, int var2)
{
    m_conn.prepare_update(source_id, var1, var2);
    m_conn.commit();

    m_conn.prepare_update(target_id, var1, var2);
    m_conn.commit();
}
```

Notice the same connection object manages both source and target connections. The connection object is not mine, and I am not allowed to change it.

Is there a way to remove the code duplication inside the methods? I thought about wrapping the methods, but I was wondering if there is a way without generating a function wrapper for every function

I thought about something like this:

```
mngr::init_wrapper(ID id,int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    m_conn.prepare_init(id, var1, var2, var3);
    m_conn.commit();
}

mngr::update_wrapper(ID id,int var1, int var2)
{
    m_conn.prepare_update(id, var1, var2);
    m_conn.commit();
}

mngr::init_conn(int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    init_wrapper(source_id, var1, var2, var3);
    init_wrapper(target_id, var1, var2, var3);
}

mngr::update_conn(int var1, int var2)
{
    update_wrapper(source_id, var1, var2);
    update_wrapper(target_id, var1, var2);
}
```

Do you have ideas of ways not generating a function wrapper for every function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a ranged `for` over `std::initializer_list`?

```
mngr::init_conn(int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
    for (auto id : {source_id, target_id})
    {
        m_conn.prepare_init(id, var1, var2, var3);
        m_conn.commit();
    }
}
```

If you need to change the `id` inside of the `for`, it should be changed to `auto &id`, otherwise changes would be discarded.

Comment: now I feel stupid :) , I should have thought of that... tnx :)